Sum up the values of specific factor levels by each group in a data.frame
Let's say I have a data.frame of the following structure:
    fac1   fac2   fac3 val
1  Apple  Fresh    Red   2
2  Apple    Old    Red   3
3  Apple Hazard    Red   1
4 Banana  Fresh Yellow   4
5 Banana    Old Yellow   5
6 Banana Hazard Yellow   1
7  Berry  Fresh Purple   1
8  Berry    Old Purple   1
9  Berry Hazard Purple   3

I want to sum up val of those rows where fac2 equals Fresh or Old for each factor level of fac1 and come up with such a data frame:
    fac1    fac3 sum.freshold
1  Apple    Red             5
2 Banana Yellow             9  
3  Berry Purple             2

Moreover, I want to specify/notate the factor levels in the condition that fac2 should equal Fresh or Old by their characters (i.e., "Fresh" and "Old"), not by the underlying integers that represent these factor levels (i.e., 1 and 2).
> str(mydf$fac2)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "Fresh","Hazard",..: 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2

Here is the example:
mydf <- data.frame(fac1 = c(rep("Apple", 3), rep("Banana", 3), rep("Berry", 3)), 
                   fac2 = rep(c("Fresh", "Old", "Hazard"), 3),
                   fac3 = c(rep("Red", 3), rep("Yellow", 3), rep("Purple", 3)), 
                   val = c(2,3,1,4,5,1,1,1,3), 
                   stringsAsFactors = T)

One attempt of mine which is not working and won't create a data.frame either:
tapply(mydf$val, mydf$fac1, function(x) {x[mydf$fac2 == "Fresh"] + x[mydf$fac2 == "Old"]})


I'm unsure about what do you want here: " I want to specify the factor levels by their characters, not their factor level integers". Change level order maybe?  @JoschiNin

The tidyverse::dplyr solution:
library(tidyverse)

# --------------------
mydf %>% 
  filter(fac2 %in% c("Fresh", "Old")) %>% 
  summarise(
    .by = c(fac1, fac3), 
    sum.freshold = sum(val))

Output:
    fac1   fac3 sum.freshold
1  Apple    Red            5
2 Banana Yellow            9
3  Berry Purple            2


An approach using aggregate
aggregate(val ~ fac1 + fac3, mydf[mydf$fac2 %in% c("Fresh", "Old"),], sum)
    fac1   fac3 val
1  Berry Purple   2
2  Apple    Red   5
3 Banana Yellow   9

Or, even nicer, directly with subset=, thanks @Onyambu
aggregate(val ~ fac1 + fac3, mydf, sum, subset = fac2 %in% c("Fresh", "Old"))

Edit, addressing naming and labels
Naming:
aggregate(cbind(sum.freshold=val) ~ fac1 + fac3, 
            mydf[mydf$fac2 %in% c("Fresh", "Old"),], sum)
    fac1   fac3 sum.freshold
1  Berry Purple            2
2  Apple    Red            5
3 Banana Yellow            9

Labels are preserved:
library(expss)

mydf <- apply_labels(mydf, fac1="factor1", fac3="factor3")

as.list(aggregate(cbind(sum.freshold=val) ~ fac1 + fac3, 
                    mydf[mydf$fac2 %in% c("Fresh", "Old"),], sum))
$fac1
LABEL: factor1 
VALUES:
Berry, Apple, Banana

$fac3
LABEL: factor3 
VALUES:
Purple, Red, Yellow

$sum.freshold
[1] 2 5 9


aggregate does have a subset parameter whereby you pass the condition to subset the data: aggregate(val ~ fac1 + fac3, mydf, sum, subset = fac2 %in% c("Fresh", "Old"))

@Onyambu Nice, yes aggregate is quite adjustable and multifunctional. Gonna add that possibility here.

Thanks a lot, both works! I upvoted. Adriano Mellos solution, however, has two benefits: 1) The resulting variable can be named immediately as sum.freshold and isn't called like the original variable val , 2) In case we have variable labels in the original data set mydf they will be preserved in the resulting data set. I didn't ask for that, but it could be useful in some cases.

I added some info regarding naming and labels.
